# How to Get Label Text from Selected Collection View Cell with CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I am trying to get the text of a label that is in a collection view cell when it is pressed. I know that doing it the regular way would involve using [indexPath.row] function however the array that the collection view is made from is with CoreData. When I try and use the [indexPath.row] it says: "'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion." This is how my didSelect function currently looks like:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellP", for: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell
    id = cell.pLabel.text![Project.name]

    print(id)
}
```

I am trying to save the text in the label of the collection view cell selected to the variable 'id'. This is the declaration of the collection view:

```
var projectList : [Project] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellP", for: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell

    let project = projectList[indexPath.row]

    cell.pLabel?.text = project.name!

    //cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

Note: Project is a CoreData entity and name is the attribute.

Does anyone know how I can save the text when cell is clicked to the 'id' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't be exposing `IBOutlet`s in your cell. Instead…

```
class CCCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    IBOutlet weak var pLabel: UILabel!

    var project: Project? {
        didSet {
            pLabel.text = project?.name       
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your view controller…

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellP", for: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell
    cell.project = projectList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and…

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell = collectionView.cellForRow(atIndexPath: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell
    let project = cell.project

    print(project)
}
```

or…

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let project = projectList[indexPath.row]

    print(project)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be dequeuing a new collectionViewCell like this inside `didSelectItemAt`. The func you are looking for is `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` which returns the cell which was selected.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CCCollectionViewCell else {
        // couldn't get the cell for some reason
        return 
    }

    id = cell.pLabel.text![Project.name] // ?

    print(id)
}
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. You stated that you want to save the cell's label.text into your `id` variable. Why are you trying to subscript the text with `[Project.name]`?